# Is their a Tier List for Talisman characters?

Tags: talisman

In short - used to play the board game like 30 years ago (& arguably I should possibly be asking this over in Role Playing) but for some odd reason thought about it this morning - now €20 lighter I have the base game and some DLCs e.g. expansions + the Samurai (as I remember that card weirdly) + the Gambler (as who doesn't like to gamble).

Just played my first game with the Gambler and got beaten up by the AI badly. In short is their a Tier List of who I should be jumping on here? E.g. the Wizard and the Druid look quite OP?

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: I have a feeling this may get closed, given a tier list is an opinion, not objective (though presumably a good one is backed with evidence). One place to look would be boardgamegeek.com's forums for Talisman, its the most well known board game site and a cursory search has turned up at least a few threads regarding tier lists and character choice.

Comment: Thanks and understood re: tier lists. Had found the site you referred to but realise that there was so many more available charachters that I thought that there might be a better approach.

Comment: Honestly it might fall under the category of "gameplay strategy and tactics" so there's hope yet if someone knows the game well or has a list they've found.